# Django - Rating System View & Template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, rating-system

I have a content that I'd like to rate on multiple criteria.
Imagine this kind of model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Criterion(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  content = models.ForeignKey(Content)

class ContRate(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, help_text="Who rated ?")
  crit = models.ForeignKey(Criterion)
  rate = models.DecimalField()
```

The user has a page displaying the content.
From this page, he can also rate the content on the criteria set

[image: Rating Criteria]

The rating will be done with Ajax.
Now I'm trying to implement the view & the template

**view.py**

```
#...
def viewcont(request, content_id):
  """The user can view a content & rate it"""
  content = get_object_or_404(Content, pk=content_id)
  RateFormSet = modelformset_factory(ContRate)
  formset = RateFormSet(queryset=ContRate.objects.filter(content=content, user=request.user))
  objs = {
    'content': content,
    'forms': formset,
  }
  return render_to_response('content/content_detail.html', objs
  , context_instance=RequestContext(request)
  )
#...
```

**content_detail.html**

```
<!-- ... -->
<div id="rating">
  <ul>
{% for crit in content.crit_set.all %}
    <li>
      {{ crit }}
      <div class="rateit"
        data-rateit-value="the_actual_rating_if_already_there"
        data-rateit-ispreset="true"
        crit-id="{{ crit.id }}"></div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Now how can I use the `forms` formset to display the actual rates ?
And how can I draw an empty form to be posted by Ajax from any clicked star ?
(I know the javascript/jQuery part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the point of the formset is here. The rates are all available via the `criteria` object, using the reverse foreign key to `ContRate` in exactly the same way as you've done from `Criteria` to `Content`.

To make this as efficient as possible, you probably want to get the relevant ratings in the view and bring them together into a single datastructure:

```
content = get_object_or_404(Content, pk=content_id)
criteria = content.criteria_set.all()
user_ratings = ContRate.objects.filter(content=content, user=request.user)
ratings_dict = dict((c.crit_id, c.rate) for c in user_ratings)
for crit in criteria:
    crit.user_rating = ratings_dict.get(crit.id)
```

Now you can pass `criteria` directly to your template, and there you can iterate through it to show the `user_rating` for each one.

(Final point: "criteria" is plural, the singular is "criterion". :-)

Comment: I was thinking of having at least a __ModelForm__ for the Ajax posts for all the criteria. Thank you for the "criterion" I didn't know that :)